# SSRS Render Report through URL

Tags: url, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have a report that is being passed parameters through the URL, but would like to have the report load by default before the user has to click the 'View Report' button.  I have rs:Command=Render in the URL but this doesn't seem to be doing it.  Is there another tag that I am missing here?  The URL is currently as follows:

```
https://server/subfolder/viewreport.aspx?Report%Name&rs:Command=Render&Parameter1=Value1&Parameter2=Value2
```

The report comes up with the appropriate values selected by default, as passed above, but it does not run until I hit View Report.  Do I need to specify all the other parameters in the report through the URL in order for it to run by default, even though those parameters already have default values?

Comment: try "http://servername/Reports"

Answer (score 0):

Found it, the report renders automatically as long as all parameters have a 'Default' value specified. Two text parameters in the report needed to have their default expressions set to =""